# FL-20 election two-party swing by precinct?

Tags: united-states, election, house-of-representatives, florida

In Florida, there was a special election held on January 11 to the US House to replace the late Alcee Hastings.

The overall swing was about 6 points towards the Democratic Party compared to the last presidential election and 2 points vs the last House election. At the county level the swing was concentrated in the more populated Broward portion.

Can someone make a swing map so I can see how the results changed from 2020's presidential results and give a link to the results if possible?

Note: I want this answer because it could help indicate trends in future elections because I want to see where it aligns with certain pockets of certain racial groups. A program called Dave's Redistricting has that data.

Comment: These types of questions ALWAYS get down-voted and I don't know why

Comment: I don't downvote them.  I think the reason that they get downvoted is that they are too specific to be of general interest. The focus on the particular results of specific districts.  I think some people have the attitude of "if you want to know, go and make your own swing map" If the data is publically available, then it just as available to you as it is for anybody else.  And if the data isn't public, then no answer is possible.  The [help] recommends "Practical questions about problems you face" - What is the problem that you face?

Comment: The problem is about the voting swing which will help me do research on demographics of the district.

Comment: I think people might feel like this is “I don’t want to do the work, do it for me” instead of a “I don’t understand this, please explain it for me” type of question.  You apparently know the data is available, where to get it, and what you’d like to see. What’s stopping you from creating the visualizations of the data yourself?

Comment: @JamesK that "problems you face" is [ancient and bad boilerplate from Stack Overflow](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1711/12102) and should be stricken from the record. [Full disclosure; I do not currently have a spacecraft in orbit around a planet who's apsidal precessions is a problem that I am facing.](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1704/12102) Related in English SE: [Difficulty understanding how the word "actual" works in "...actual problems that you face."](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/558286/217285)

Answer (score 0):

Precinct-level 2020 election results for FL-20 can be found [here](https://enr.electionsfl.org/PAL/2801/Summary/) (Palm Beach County) and [here](https://enr.electionsfl.org/BRO/2807/Summary/) (Broward County). The results for the 2022 special election may be found [here](https://enr.electionsfl.org/PAL/Summary/3122/) (PBC) and [here](https://enr.electionsfl.org/BRO/3123/Summary/) (Broward).

Roughly a third of the 297 precincts swung towards the Republican candidate, while the remaining two-thirds swung towards the Democratic candidate. The mean result was a 0.97 point swing towards the Democratic candidate. These results should really be taken in the context of a special election, though; the turnout in this election was roughly 17% of that in the 2020 general election.

This is demonstrated by the precincts which saw the largest swings - the largest swing to the Republicans was in precinct 6034 in Palm Beach County -  two votes for the Republican candidate in 2022 compared to three votes for the Democratic candidate and one vote for the Republican in 2020. The precinct with the largest swing to the Democrats was precinct 6082, also in Palm Beach County, with 1 vote for the Democrat in 2022 compared to 15 votes for the Democrat & 12 votes for the Republican in 2020.

Collating this data & using the shapefiles for the county voter precincts in each county found [here](https://www.pbcelections.org/Records-Data/Voting-District-Maps) & [here](https://geohub-bcgis.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/123aa35acf664fdc8facc902b29027ec_0/), we can create the following two-party swing map. Note that the district doesn't look contiguous because the water conservation areas are omitted from the shapefiles.

[image]